# New line with specific height in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a text that has a certain font and font-size:

```
<span class="fs-font" style="font-size: 160%;">Insert some text here</span>
```

I want to insert under it an empty line that has the same height as the text above.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do but have you tried `margin-bottom`? If you try this make sure to set `span` as `display: inline-block;`

Comment: ....shouldn't inline styles be gone for years?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.fs-font::after` to create an element below your span. If you set both heights to be the same, you have a line of text with no text in it below your span.

Answer (score 0):

Use sudo element selector `:after`.

working demo

```css
span.fs-font {
    font-size: 160%;
    position: relative;
}

.fs-font:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="fs-font">Insert some text here</span>
```